# How to implement batch or group id for excel file into SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have tried to find answers to this to no avail, if someone has posted this question before please direct me to them.

My question is how can I assigned a id/group number to a excel sqlbulkcopy upload to a sql table. What I am trying to accomplish is to associate all rows with a common ID that are inserted from the excel upload so that I can pull that specific group of rows at a later time. Let me know if I need to explain this better, thanks for the help ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way we've done in our project is

1. Have a NULLable column(say `GroupID`) in the destination table
2. do Bulk copy
3. Get the `ISNULL(max(GroupID),1)` from the destination table and store in variable say `@groupId` (int)
4. Add 1 to the `@groupId`
5. Update all rows in the destination table, setting the value to `GroupID=@groupId WHERE GroupID is NULL`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up doing something similar by retrieving the max value from the batchid column then store that into a vb.net variable and add 1 then add that to all rows in the sqlbulkcopy excel file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim batchid As Integer
        Dim con2 As New SqlConnection(Session("strconnection"))
        Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand()
        cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT max(batchid) as batchid FROM purchasingrequest"
        cmd2.Connection = con2

        con2.Open()
        Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader
            While dr.Read

                batchid = dr("batchid")

            End While
        End Using
        con2.Close()
        con2.Dispose()
        MsgBox(batchid)

        Dim newbatchid As Integer = batchid + 1
```